# How can I initialize a new string array from the values contained in a char array?

Tags: c#

I would like to initialize a new string array from the values contained in a char array.
Is this possible without using a list?

This is what I have so far:

```
char[] arrChars = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
string[] arrStrings = new string[](arrChars);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string[] arrStrings = Array.ConvertAll(arrChars, c => c.ToString());
```

Comment: This one is nice too, because it's more clear what is happening if you're not familiar with Linq's Select method

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a for loop for your initialization?  Or, if that's too many LOC, you could just use Linq:

```
string[] arrStrings = arrChars.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: This is about the most compact way to go, nice one.

Answer (score 2):

.NET 2:

```
char[] arrChars = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
string[] arrStrings = Array.ConvertAll<char, string>(arrChars, delegate(char c)
{
    return c.ToString();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

using LINQ......

```
char[] arrChars = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
string[] arrStrings =( from c in arrChars select "" + c).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] arrStrings = arrChars.Select( c => new String(new []{c}) ).ToArray();
```

or

```
string[] arrStrings = arrChars.Select( c => c.ToString() ).ToArray();
```